# Get acceleration data from Samsung smartwatch (Tizen)

Tags: accelerometer, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear, tizen-studio

I am new to Tizen implementations.
I try to get acceleration data from my Samsung Smartwatch via Tizen studio. I would like to ask if there is a way to access these data directly from the Tizen studio or should I create (probably) an API to store these data.

PS. Any help with tutorials will be valuable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tizen supports .NET Application by using Visual Studio Community 2019 + Tizen Plugin + Tizen Base SDK (for emulator).
https://docs.tizen.org/application/vstools/install/

You can find a sample application here: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen-CSharp-Samples/tree/master/Wearable/Xamarin.Forms/Sensors

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help. At this point, I am trying to save these sensor data. Is there any possible way to write and save data at eg .txt or .csv form?